# Github prevents posting PR comments - "Line must be part of the diff"

Tags: github

I have a weird GitHub issue. When commenting on a certain PR, the message "Line must be part of the diff" appears and prevents the comment from being posted. This happens in both Firefox and Google Chrome of the latest versions and only on this particular PR. Other PRs in the repo don't have this issue. Clearing caches and cookies had no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1338)?

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes. It's not the same issue and they report it fixed, while mine is not.

Comment: I saw that they reported the issue is fixed, but one comment there (before the fix) suggested a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing any commit can fix this.